# Python 'astype' not working

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

I am currently using Spyder from Anaconda and I am trying to convert an array containing type float to type int:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 2.5])
x.astype(int)
print x
```

The result still comes out unchanged:

```
[1. 2. 2.5]
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 21):

[`astype` returns a new array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html). You need to assign the result to `x`:

```
In [298]: x = x.astype(int)

In [299]: x
Out[299]: array([1, 2, 2])
```

Comment: When I print it in the program now, it works. But when I try to write it out to a file, it gets written out in float/scientific notation. How do I get it to write to a file as int?
(I am using:

    np.savetxt(outfile_name, array, header = str(dimension),      comments = '')
)

Comment: Use `np.savetxt(outfile_name, array, fmt='%d', ...)`

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot that astype returns a value