# Matrix of Image pixel value is in float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, matrix

I am creating matrix from image pixel values, but when I write those matrix in a file using the following code:

[image: code]

The written file looks like this:

[image: file]

But I need these values as integers. I tried `(ro.astype(np.int64) or np.astype(int))`, but it failed.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please [post text, not screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3005167). What do you mean by *astype failed*, what happens (error message, crash, nothing, ...)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 'astype' not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143850/python-astype-not-working)

Comment: I think astype convert matrix into int matrix, if you specified int or int64, but it can't convert the matrix into integer.

Comment: I have used this, ro = ro.astype(np.int64), but not converting into int matrix.

Comment: thnaks, now I have done it. By using this code:
        ro = ro.astype(np.int64)
        fn = "images/file-" + str(st) + "-%angle.csv" % angle
        np.savetxt(fn,ro,fmt='%d',delimiter=",")