# Matplotlib y axis not displaying from low values to high values

Tags: matplotlib, plot, spyder

i'm a newbie in spyder especially matplotlib. Currently i am trying to display stock price data from dates of 2014-2019.

The unexpected errors i have encountered are the display of data is incorrect .

There are 2 flaws and workarounds i have attempted.

Is the error in displaying caused due to the first index being the year 2019 instead of the year 2014?

Flaw 1 : plt.yticks([0,140]) Does not even display ticks from 0 to 140.
[Not displaying ticks from 0 to 140](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeAEQ.png)

Flaw 2 : If i remove the conversion of the Date to a datetime format. The display error will be half rectified but a new error will be displayed as the x axis cannot be displayed correctly.
[Data is presented correctly from descending to ascending order but date cannot be displayed as it is not in datetime format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aww7n.png)

In essence the main flaw is the tickers of the y axis cannot be displayed and the data needs to be presented in descending to ascending order.
I've spent hours trying to fix this, my hair is falling off, i'm gonna be bald soon.

The data is read from year 2019 to 2014.
As the data is organized as of column 1 is: 2019 and the last column is 2014.

I understand that the data is cramped during display but even changing the view to automatic and not inline will not solve this issue.

The code is as below

```
file = 'Microsoft.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)
## convert timestamp
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%m/%d/%Y')
# df['Close'] = df['Close'].str.replace('$', '')
# df['Close'].astype('float')

##Not Necessary
# df['Close'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
# df.Close = float(df.Close)
# df['Close']  = df.Close.astype(float)

##Beginning of plot
plt.plot(df.Date, df.Close)
plt.yticks([0,140])
plt.ylim(0, 1511)


plt.suptitle('Stock Price')
plt.title('Microsoft', fontdict={'fontsize':15,'fontweight':'bold'})
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Price in USD')
plt.show()
```

This is the original plotting without adding the yticks.
[X-axis not converted to datetime, Y-Axis does not have yticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyNBM.png)

Any help would be grateful, the goal is to display the plot from descending to ascending order with yticks being able to display from any order 0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140 or any amount.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot string values in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497449/plot-string-values-in-matplotlib)

Comment: You are probably plotting strings. Try assigning the result of `astype` everywhere.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143850/python-astype-not-working

Comment: See also the dollar signs in your yticklabels.

Comment: as the above code i have removed the dollar signs also.

I think what u said i right. It is a string value. i checked the type.
I will try converting it to a float value. Either by code or straight through the excel vba command. 

Thank you i didnt checked if it was a string as i thought the .astype('float') converted it into a float. But it didn't ... What a sneaky little..!@#$%^&*().

I'll get back after i converted it to a float and retry the code.

Comment: Note that all your conversion code is commented out... Your first block of conversions together with assigning astype() will probably work.

Comment: It is solved. I edited the value using excel 
Thank you Andras. A simple 5 minute fix . Hours spent, owh programming why u gotta do this everytime.

Comment: I uncommented it but it still didnt change the astype, i might be doing it wrong. Even in a for loop as the code would be for x in df['Close'] : df[x].astype['Float']. Either way i fixed it already. the picture is beautiful i will edit the question. to solved. Thank you once again.

Comment: No problem. But what I was trying to say is that `.astype` doesn't change the inputs, it returns a new copy. So you need `df['Close'] = df['Close'].astype(float)`. But I was on mobile so I couldn't explain with code easily. Since your problem was more or less a misunderstanding and you solved it outside python, you can delete your question because it's unlikely to help future readers. You can delete questions without any repercussions as long as there are no votes and answers on it :)